# How do I get attribute/option values from XML with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I need to extract the URL from this tag:

```
<media:content url="http://video.ted.com/talk/podcast/2011/None/MikeMatas_2011.mp4" fileSize="15533795" type="video/mp4" />
```

Currently I use this code but I only get nil values:

```
page_content = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.ted.com/talks/rss"))

page_content.xpath('//item').each {|item|
   @url = course_hash[:videoUrl] = item.at_xpath('[media:content]')['url']
   puts @url
}
```

Comment: It would help to know the URL to the XML you are retrieving, or have a small, cut-down, sample of the XML, including the `xmlns` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The node you are trying to access has a `media` namespace, so you'll need to take that into account when you try to locate it.

Generally we'd do something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = %q{
<xml xmlns:media="http://xml.my.org/file">
 <media:content url="http://video.ted.com/talk/podcast/2011/None/MikeMatas_2011.mp4" fileSize="15533795" type="video/mp4" /> 
</xml>
}

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.search('//media:content', 'media' => 'http://xml.my.org/file').each do |n|
  puts n['url']
end
# >> http://video.ted.com/talk/podcast/2011/None/MikeMatas_2011.mp4
```

Nokogiri will automatically register the namespace if it is defined in the `<xml>` tag, meaning we could use a simpler form:

```
doc.search('//media:content').each do |n|
  puts n['url']
end
# >> http://video.ted.com/talk/podcast/2011/None/MikeMatas_2011.mp4
```

Nokogiri also supports using CSS accessors with namespaces:

```
doc.search('media|content').each do |n|
  puts n['url']
end
# >> http://video.ted.com/talk/podcast/2011/None/MikeMatas_2011.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your xpath expression is messed up: try using `item.at_xpath('media:content')['url']` instead.

Comment: It was, just:item.xpath('media:content').first['url']

Comment: `item.at_xpath('media:content')['url']` should act the same as `item.xpath('media:content').first['url']`. `at_xpath(expression)` is shorthand for `xpath(expression).first` (http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath)